# APEX ORACLE - Disable a region dynamically with PL/SQL + Javascript

Tags: oracle-apex

I have different regions in my main page. What I want to accomplish is to disable dynamically one or more regions based on the logged user.

I have already managed to disable one region in a 'static way'. In the page attributes, under the JavaScript menu, in `Execute when Page Loads` I put this code:

```
$('#R4').addClass('apex_disabled').attr('tabindex', '-1');
```

Where `R4` is the `ID` of one of the regions.

For the 'dynamic way' I created a `Process`. For example, if the user is `ADMIN`, I want to disable the region `R4`. This is the code (for now I'm not checking the user, i'm just trying to get working the disable functionality):

```
    DECLARE
    user VARCHAR2 (50);

    BEGIN

    select username into user
    from USER
    where username = V('APP_USER');


    htp.p (' <script type = "text/javascript"> ');
    htp.p (' function disableRegion()');
    htp.p (' { ');
    htp.p (' 
    $(''#R4'').addClass(''apex_disabled'').attr(''tabindex'',''-1''); ');
    htp.p (' } ');
    htp.p (' </script> ');


    END;
```

This is not working. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A server side condition is normal, where you can have any form of declarative expression, or PL/SQL or SQL queries etc.
These may not be toggled back on once page is rendered, as they don't get rendered in the first place.

A client side condition may be from a dynamic action firing on page load, which could also be protected by authorisation scheme, so only certain dynamic actions exist to fire. But as someone suggested, this is not secure.

The code provided would never exist in a well written APEX application, though I do suspect perhaps the OP is on APEX 3.x, or learned there.

Comment: I'm on Apex 4.2, I'm learning here. So the best solution is to change the authorization scheme on the region?

Comment: Yes, if you would like to not display certain regions/buttons to certain users, then authorisation schemes are the way to go. And I recommend you apply schemes by feature, not business role, IMHO, but that's a far deeper discussion

Comment: Thanks! One more question: as I mentioned in the answer I want to only disable a particular region, not hide it. Is that still possible with the auth schemes?

Comment: And by disable, you mean adding a particular class? You could either run this as dynamic action (conditional with auth scheme), or conditionally compute an item and substitute it into the region classes.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

The script needs to be launched `On Load - After Regions`.

Mine was set to `On Load - Before Header`.

So It was not able to get the `ID` of the regions.

Comment: You could also just change the authorization scheme on the particular region, e.g. for `R4` choose `Not Admin` (assuming you have an admin authorization scheme).

Comment: @RLOG agree, and that would be a stronger approach imho. The current method could be easily circumvented. Maybe that's a non issue in the OP's environment.